# Refusing to start with libssl version OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 0x1000105f (1.0.1e release) (in range 1.0.1 dev - 1.0.1f release)

Tags: configuration, centos7, radius, freeradius

I have install Freeradius v3.0 from git repository
after that i run `radiusd -X` 
and i have this error

```
Refusing to start with libssl version OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 0x1000105f (1.0.1e release) (in range 1.0.1 dev - 1.0.1f release)
Security advisory CVE-2014-0160 (Heartbleed)
For more information see http://heartbleed.com
Once you have verified libssl has been correctly patched, set security.allow_vulnerable_openssl = 'CVE-2014-0160'
```

I try to change `allow_vulnerable_openssl = 'CVE-2014-0160'` in file radius.conf

And try again but, still the same error

Also i don't know what this mean **Once you have verified libssl has been correctly patched**

The version of openssl i have on Centos 7 is : **OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013**

Answer (score 1):

Locate the

```
# SECURITY CONFIGURATION
#
#  There may be multiple methods of attacking on the server.  This
#  section holds the configuration items which minimize the impact
#  of those attacks
#
security {

}
```

Stanza in radiusd.conf

Add `allow_vulnerable_openssl = 'CVE-2014-0160'` between the curly braces.

e.g.

```
# SECURITY CONFIGURATION
#
#  There may be multiple methods of attacking on the server.  This
#  section holds the configuration items which minimize the impact
#  of those attacks
#
security {
     allow_vulnerable_openssl = 'CVE-2014-0160'
}
```

> Once you have verified libssl has been correctly patched

Means, once you have checked that the packages on your local system have had the fix for CVE-2014-0160 applied, then you may set that configuration item.

Its to make you aware that OpenSSL of that version has a known, severe, and remotely exploitable vulnerability.

Comment: I do exactly as you explain 
and make sure that libssl has fixed i run the command 

 `rpm -q --changelog openssl | grep -i -E "CVE-2014-0160"`
and i have this
`- fix CVE-2014-0160 - information disclosure in TLS heartbeat extension`
but still have the same error

Comment: After i change `allow_vulnerable_openssl = 'CVE-2014-0160'` in file radius.conf and run `radiusd -X` 
i see in debug `security{allow_vulnerable_openssl = "no"}` shall i do anything else after change `allow_vulnerable_openssl = 'CVE-2014-0160'`
cause i think it reading this value from another file

Comment: Yes, sounds like the wrong file.  You should be editing ``/etc/raddb/radiusd.conf``.  You can force the server to use that config directory by passing ``-d /etc/raddb/``.

Comment: I found another place `/usr/local/etc/raddb` is running, when i change the the `allow_vulnerable_openssl = 'CVE-2014-0160'` in file `radiusd.conf` it works :D 
Thanks alot